# offsets are committed even when pods are restarted.(Kafka listener)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am using kafka listener on single partition topic, I have single consumer per pod
and i have 2 pods running ( other being idle consumer).

When my pod restarted for some reason i see KafkaMessageListenerConatiner is trying to commit some offset.i.e 10 i.e (9 consumed +1)

When other consumer(pod) received onPartionAssigned during rebalance it started consuming from 11th (committed +1) offset
ideally it should consume from commited offset.

Why the last offset commited is not being replayed or how come it is committing next offset when pod restart.

Here is my code and configuration

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{topicProvider.getOffsetStorageTopicName()}", idIsGroup = false)
    public void handleMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        try {
            consumeOffsetRecords(record);
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Error thrown while consuming message {}, record offset{}", exception.getMessage(), record.offset());
            acknowledgment.nack(Duration.ofMillis(60000));
        }
    }
```

configs :

```
@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, DmpKafkaSecurityService
        dmpKafkaSecurityService, TopicProvider topicProvider) throws DMPException {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBrokerUrl());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, topicProvider.getOffsetStorageTopicName() + HYPHEN + "restore-tracker");
        props.put(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        props.put(ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
       
      
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
```

```
@Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory, RestoreStatusTracker restoreStatusTracker) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        //single consumer per container
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.INFO);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerRebalanceListener(restoreStatusTracker);
        return factory;
    }
```

I want when pod restart it consumer should consume from last record committed.
to maintain atleast once delivery